Is it believed that statements exist whose independence cannot be proven even if we start using large cardinal axioms?
Here are some observations: Gödel's proof of his theorem invokes an unprovable statement. In a stronger system that accepts the original system was consistent (which may be the result of a large cardinal), it is possible to prove the undecidability of this statement. Secondly, AC and CH are provably independent of ZF and ZFC when we again work in a system that proves the consistency of one of those theories (which again can come from a large cardinal). The consistency of ZFC doesn't prove that large cardinals are consistent, but it seems like enough large cardinal axioms remedy that.
So, is it believed that by adding more and more large cardinal axioms we will be able to determine the dependence of any result we want? Is this a motivating reason for defining large cardinals?

“Large cardinals” is sort of a vague, catch-all term. But in a sense you can certainly prove any result of the form Con(ZFC + $\phi$) that is true (let’s ignore for a second what “true” means in this context) in ZFC + the existence of a “suitably large” large cardinal, just by defining $\kappa$ to be “suitably large” iff $V_\kappa \models \text{ZFC} + \phi$.

(AC and CH are sort of bad examples, though. ZFC is equiconsistent with ZF and ZFC + CH is equiconsistent with ZFC, meaning one is consistent iff the other is, while large cardinals are generally used to measure consistency strength of theories that are strictly stronger than ZFC - say, ZFC + Con(ZFC) has strictly stronger consistency strength than ZFC itself, though it is weaker than ZFC + there exists an inaccessible cardinal.)
